# Forwarding device file traffic over ssh to another pc

Tags: linux, ssh, devices

I have the following situation. `DEV1 <---> PC1 <---> PC2`

`DEV1` is connected over serial to `PC1` where a device file is created in `/dev/ttyUSB0`. `PC1` and `PC2` are in the same network. I can always just ssh from `PC2` into `PC1` and then open the serial port and communicate with `DEV1` but i want to automate this, to skip ssh-ing into `PC1`.

Anyone knows any way to do this? somehow to create an alias of `/dev/ttyUSB0` from `PC1` to `PC2` maybe? My goal is to have a device file created on `PC2` which does all the ssh connection in the background, so from the `PC2` user's point of view, he just communicates directly with the `DEV1`

Comment: Just to clarify automate, are you wanting to make a chron job to automatically transfer the file? Or a script you can run to make the file transfer?

Comment: @Gordon no copying is needed, it's not an actual file, it's a device file, so in a sense i want to redirect the input and output to another device file on another PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB/IP is a way to expose USB devices on the network

http://usbip.sourceforge.net/

or `usbip`  package on debian

Comment: Exactly what i needed.